# Как с помощью peewee записать в бд SQLite данные из готового списка, состоящим из кортежей?

Tags: python, peewee

Cоздал базу данных и столбцы, а теперь в них нужно записать значения из списка, который состоит из tuple:

```
test = [
    ('1', 'собака', 'молоко', 'дом'), 
    ('12', 'кошка', 'молоко', 'дом')
]
```

Cтолбцы в базе: цифра, животное, продукты, тип помещения.

Comment: советую почитать [туториал](http://zetcode.com/python/peewee/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ваша модель примерно такая:

```
class Pet(Model):
    number = IntegerField()
    animal = CharField()
    food = CharField()
    house = CharField()
```

то [сохранить данные](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#storing-data) можно обходом списка кортежей test:

```
for item in test:
    pet = Pet(
        number=item[0]
        animal=item[1]
        food=item[2]
        house=item[3]
    )
    pet.save()
```

PS кортежи лучше сразу заменить словарями, чтоб не было проблем с изменением последовательности данных, имхо...